# VS 2010 / Resharper 5 Mouse Behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

After upgrading to the above configuration I notice that
1) CTRL-Click on a type highlights the type but doesn't take me to the declaration,
2) Clicking on some closure (ie, like a method) toggles whether it's expanded or collapsed.

Since these are both mouse related tasks I figure there is some setting in either VS or R# that I need to change, but I sure can't figure out what it is.

Anybody know?

Cheers,
Berryl

PS - there is an option in R# to ctrl-click to the type but I have that checked and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's an open bug about this on their bug tracker.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-178610?projectKey=RSRP&query=%22left+click%22

Maybe if you vote it up, or complain to support, they might fix it faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is in regards to the CTRL click behavior:

At first I thought it wasn't working either, but then I realized that it just works differently (not as good IMO):

If you quickly go CTRL-Click, nothing happens.  But if you hold down CTRL, until a blue underline appears, and THEN click, it goes to the definition (for me anyway).

Comment: No, this is just not acceptable and I'm shocked jet brains hasn't been able to fix this by now! You could write the code for the definition and grab a sandwich by the time R# takes you there!

Comment: Agreed.  Not only does the "underline" take a while to show up, but going to the definition takes way longer than in 4.5