# Resharper 5 shortcuts & keyboard schemes

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, resharper-5.0

I am used to Finding Usages by hitting Shift-F12, but after switch to R# 5 on vs 2010 that one isn't obviously available.

I've got the keyboard scheme set to Visual Studio, as opposed to the only other choice which is R# v2/IntelliJ (the shortcut for usages in that scheme is Alt-F7).

Can anyone help me get back to Shift F12 through a R# setting?

Cheers,
Berryl

EDIT

I can use VS to set any keyboard command I want , of course. BUT in light of other [buggy R# 5.0 behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669245/vs-2010-resharper-5-mouse-behavior) I am wondering why the old shortcut isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you update the VS keyboard mapping?

In VS
Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> Search for command "ReSharper.FindUsages"

Comment: I think R# s/b configured the same as it used to be but I just updated the keyboard mapping for now. Cheers